# Sqlite rejecting quoted value as ambiguous column name

Tags: sqlite

I'm using Sqlite 3.7.11 with Windows x64 Visual Studio 2010.  The example below can be run from the sqlite3.exe tool.  I get the same failures from code.

Given this table:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;

CREATE TABLE hashes( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, hash CHARACTER(4) NOT NULL UNIQUE );
CREATE TABLE sources( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, source VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE );
CREATE TABLE files( hash_id INTEGER, source_id INTEGER, filename VARCHAR(2048), extension VARCHAR(16),  
FOREIGN KEY(hash_id) REFERENCES hashes(id) 
FOREIGN KEY(source_id) REFERENCES sources(id) 
UNIQUE( hash_id, source_id, filename ) );
```

And this initial data:

```
INSERT INTO hashes VALUES( ?, "abcd" );
INSERT INTO sources VALUES( ?, "mysource" );
```

I'm adding rows like this.  The files tables is referencing the hash and source tables per the constraints above.

```
INSERT INTO files ( hash_id, source_id, filename, extension ) 
SELECT hashes.id, sources.id, "filename.ext", "ext" 
FROM hashes, sources 
WHERE hashes.hash = "abcd" AND sources.source = "mysource";
```

Everything works fine until 'id' shows up in either the filename or extension field.  This doesn't make any sense -- it's quoted.  Both of these inserts will fail:

```
INSERT INTO files ( hash_id, source_id, filename, extension ) 
SELECT hashes.id, sources.id, "id", "" 
FROM hashes, sources 
WHERE hashes.hash = "abcd" AND sources.source = "mysource";

INSERT INTO files ( hash_id, source_id, filename, extension ) 
SELECT hashes.id, sources.id, "filename.id", "id" 
FROM hashes, sources 
WHERE hashes.hash = "abcd" AND sources.source = "mysource";
```

**Error: ambiguous column name: id**

Do I need to further escape the quoted value somehow?

Comment: Where does the last "id" belongs to? I mean, which column is that "id"?

Comment: The quoted "id" is the filename in first failing example and the extension in the second failing example.  The column should contain the literal string "id" after the insert.

Comment: Shouldn't they be on the where clause as (filename LIKE "filename.id" AND extension LIKE "id") ?

Comment: Found the solution.  I need to use single quotes around string literals.  Change all the instances of " to ' above and it works as intended.
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ... that was a rookie mistake.  This works once I used single quotes to indicate string literals:

```
INSERT INTO files ( hash_id, source_id, filename, extension ) 
SELECT hashes.id, sources.id, "id", "" 
FROM hashes, sources 
WHERE hashes.hash = "abcd" AND sources.source = "mysource";

INSERT INTO files ( hash_id, source_id, filename, extension ) 
SELECT hashes.id, sources.id, 'filename.id', 'id' 
FROM hashes, sources 
WHERE hashes.hash = "abcd" AND sources.source = "mysource";
```